# use two version of jquery at one page

Tags: javascript

I want to use two version of jquery at one page but how?Here I want to use jquery-1.8.1.min.js" with bellow script and jquery-1.3.2.min.j with another

```
     <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>

 $(document).ready (function(){

  $('.following').hover(function(){
      $(this).text("Unfollow");
    },function(){
       $(this).text("Following");
    });

    $('.following').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('following follow').unbind("hover");
    if($(this).is('.follow')){
        $(this).text("Follow");
    }
    else{

        $(this).bind({
            mouseleave:function(){$(this).text("Following");},
            mouseenter:function(){$(this).text("Unfollow");}      
        });
    }
  });
}); 





 </script>
```

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: Namespace support in 1.2 is usually the only reason to do this

Comment: No recommendable - the best question is why? And what can you do to pull the old script into v1.edge at least

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you should rewrite the scripts to use the same version of jQuery. The code that you show isn't very complicated, and should be possible to rewrite easily enough.

Anyhow, using the [`noConflict` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), you can use two version of jQuery. You would need to put one of the scripts in a scope where the `$` identifier references the new version. By Calling `$.noClonflict(true)` jQuery will reinstate the first version loaded and return a reference to the second version loaded:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function($){
  // in here $ is the 1.8.1 version

  $(document).ready (function(){

    $('.following').hover(function(){
      $(this).text("Unfollow");
    },function(){
       $(this).text("Following");
    });

    $('.following').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('following follow').unbind("hover");
      if($(this).is('.follow')){
        $(this).text("Follow");
      } else{

        $(this).bind({
          mouseleave:function(){$(this).text("Following");},
          mouseenter:function(){$(this).text("Unfollow");}      
        });
      }
    });
  }); 

}($.noConflict(true)));

// from here on $ is the 1.3.2 version

</script>
```

If you want to keep a reference to the second version also:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var $$ = $.noConflict(true);

// from here on $ is the 1.3.2 version and $$ is the 1.8.1 version

(function($){

  // in here $ is the 1.8.1 version

}($$));

</script>
```

Comment: Much better solution than mine :) I'm curious, what does the second version actually become in this case?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: I added comments in the code to show which version is used where.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're doing there. Won't this keep the new version from being used from here on out though? Once that anon function is done executing the old version is used, so it's possible OP may need to get the new version back.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: Yes, once the reference is used in the function call it's gone. To keep it for later you would first assign the result from the `noConflict` call to a variable, then use the variable in the function call that encapsulates the code.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. Just wanted to make sure we were on the same page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's doable due to jQuery's noconflict mode. http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using noConflict(). It's not really meant for this sort of thing if you look at the jQuery source. I recommend the following:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var jQueryOld = $old = jQuery</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery source for noConflict()

```
jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
        if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
                window.$ = _$;
        }

        if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
                window.jQuery = _jQuery;
        }

        return jQuery;
};
```

Basically you'll still end up with two objects named jQuery once all is said and done. Additionally, to use this with jQuery you have to say jQuery.noConflict(true), and if you read the docs:

"If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version."

Comment: NOTE: My solution may not be 100% foolproof, but it's a starting point.